# Problems running NetLogo with BitDefender

Tags: jvm, antivirus, netlogo, bitdefender

Pretty frustrating, yet hopefully small problem I'm running into.
I've just downloaded and installed NetLogo 5.0.5 for my windows 8 machine, standard install in to Program Files (x86). When I try to run the .exe I get this error message

> The JVM could not be started. The maximum heap size (-Xmx) me be too large or an antivirus or firewall tool could block the execution.

I've been through the NetLogo User guide recommended protocols of accessing the .vmoptions file and changing

> -Xmx1024m

to

> -Xmx512m

in order to solve the max heap size issue, but I'm still receiving the same error message. I'm assuming therefore that it has something to do with my antivirus or firewall. I've recently switched my antivirus from Norton Internet Security to Bitdefender, and this is when the problem started to appear.

Any suggestions?

Much thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling "BitDefender Java" gives a bunch of results indicating that BitDefender is aggressive about blocking Java-based software (such as NetLogo).  The most useful-seeming link I see is:

- http://forum.bitdefender.com/index.php?showtopic=28551

but you might try the search yourself and see what you turn up.

So it seems this primarily a question about BitDefender, rather than primarily a question about NetLogo. If you need help configuring BitDefender, perhaps someone here can help you. Or, you might have better luck at http://forum.bitdefender.com or http://superuser.com than here; Stack Overflow is primarily for programming questions.

Comment: Right on. Diving into the Bitdefender forums is getting me in the right direction. I'll post more once I get the problem solved

Comment: From the link above:

"Open BitDefender, go to 'Settings' -> 'Antivirus' tab -> 'Exclusions' and click on 'Excluded processes'. Click on the 'Add' button to add the EXE file in question so it won't be scanned/blocked by AVC. Restart the PC again to see if the issue still occur."

Thanks Seth!